# MySQL Error 111 Can't connect to server

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a connection.php file that is suppose to connect to a remote database.
Here is the code:

```
<?php
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=IP;port=PORT;dbname=DBNAME', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
} 
?>
```

Now all my variables I believe are correct since I can connect to the database through [Toad](http://www.quest.com/toad/%E2%80%8E). I used this same PDO format for my own database connection through localhost and it works fine. I am not sure what the problem is. Since i can use [Toad](http://www.quest.com/toad/%E2%80%8E) i believe that the server already allows remote access to it, but i am not sure on that. Any input would be nice.

Also this is the Error that PDOException is coming back with:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'IP' (111)
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/access-denied.html

Comment: How can Toad connect to my database when my file cannot? Do they not connect the same way and both need the same remote permissions? Example: they both need bind-address to work? or not work?

Answer (score 4):

111 means *connection refused*,

It probably means that your MySQL server is only listening the `localhost` interface.

If you have lines like this :

```
skip-networking
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

You should comment them In your my.cnf configuration file (add a # at the beginning of the lines), and restart MySQL.

Comment: Even though i can connect through Toad and view the database it can still be only listening on the localhost?

Answer (score 2):

well, in you /etc/mysql/my.cnf :
you should find out this:

```
skip-networking
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

You gotta comment the first one, and change the ip to 0.0.0.0 or to the ip of your remote host that you want to allow (recommended)
Also, you may don't have a user to connect to that host, i mean, mysql users are like 'root'@'192.168.1.1', so you may try to access with a user that doesn't exists. Try to create it and then grant to it all privilegies. 
Just execute this couple commands on mysql:

`CREATE USER 'root'@'192.168.1.100' IDENTIFIED BY  '***';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO  'root'@'192.168.1.100' IDENTIFIED BY  '***';`

Also, make sure that mysql is listening to in the right port, if using linux:

`netstat -tlpn`

should do the work, at least that's how i fixed similar problems.

Comment: This is the working solution for me. Comment the bind-address doesn't work. I uncomment it and change it to 0.0.0.0, then it works like charm. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error for a few hours now.
Turns out I had given the wrong port in my code.

My port to connect was the default **port 3306 I was using 3327.**

Hope it helps someone maybe.