# EC2 instance and EC2 hosted sql is crashing

Tags: python, mysql, django, amazon-ec2

I have a copied one Django project and deleted the migration files other than `init.py` and deployed that to a new EC2 instance with new url. But whenever I am performing any sql operation like insert and update, my EC2 instance is getting crashed after sometime of getting this error.Even I couldn’t open the admin page

> med_new/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
> wargs)
> med_new/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 234, in get_new_connection
> connect(**conn_params)
> med_new/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 353, in **init**

> med_new/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 664, in connect

> lError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")

After this the EC2 is crashing always. What fix I have to do for that?

I want the connection between the SQL and EC2 to be stable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Error 111 Can't connect to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219338/mysql-error-111-cant-connect-to-server)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my config file .It was pointing to local host.After changing it was resolved